# Issue with adding Android map (with Google API) to android app

Tags: android

I tried to add a Google map to my Android app, as the tutorial said by [Google Maps Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/).

In demos and sample code section I tried 'Hello map' example. But when I launched this `mapActivity` the app shows **"app stopped"** message.

I did the following

1) Created activity implementing `onMapReadycallback`

2) Added a map `<fragment>` in layout file.

3) Added this fragment by
    `getFragmentById(R.id.map)` function in Java code.

4) Implemented method: `onMapReady(GoogleMap map){......}`

5) Added permissions `internet`,`access_network_state` in Manifest

But still the app stops , plz help me techiezzzz......

Comment: Please post the logcat / error message shown when the app crashes.

Comment: Sorry i will post it sooon..thnx for support

Comment: Check the android monitor in the bottom of the android studio IDE .

Comment: Thnx I will check it...

Comment: The logcat floods with enormous msgs...which one i want to copy or at which time (like app stop)

Comment: When the app crashes.. There will be something written in red color.. Showing the exact error you are getting

Comment: Have you generated the debug key for accessing the mapAPI?

Comment: @AmeyaKulkarni no whats it ?

Comment: AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user0.iot, PID: 31324
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user0.iot/com.example.user0.iot.Mappane}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)

Comment: Above thing is my logcat output

Comment: I think generating the API key will solve your problem

Comment: I reached upto console pagr for getting api key ,but it is not showing the keys, the loading blue circle is only showing.....nothing shows in "credentials tab"

Answer (score 0):

To accesss the map you need to generate the DebugAPI key. Go to the very same website of documentation and then click on get API KEY. Generate the Android Debug API key and add it in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Follow these steps 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Comment: Without the API Key you are not allowed to access the maps. Here there can be 2 possible problems 1. Key is not generated 2. There is some bug in the code. I request you to add the API Key and also post the code if possible so that any possible bug can be found out

Comment: The rarest possibility is that if you have created the activity class manually then you might have forgot to mention the <activity ></activity> tag for that activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: No added activity by android studio activity entry right on the Manifest

Comment: Can u provide bug free code for adding google map to android activity?

Comment: , PID: 2365

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user0.iot/com.example.user0.iot.Mappane}: 

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
    
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment

Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment that is not a Fragment

Comment: But the map isnt showing......i am using another one's API KEY (got from Github) is it make trouble?(another package's key)

Comment: You need to get key on your own package name

Comment: But the developers console only showing the loading icon....not the credentials on chrome

Comment: private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
                 
In the above code snippet(java) what is the use of things inside <>
ie, <String....>